# How to count number of records in an SQL database with python

Tags: python, sql, database

I can't seem to print the number of records in my database:
When I program:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()   
count = cursor.execute("select count(*) from fixtures")  
cursor.commit  
print (count)
```

(fixtures is the name of my database)
I get:

```
pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x00000000032FC150
```

...rather than the number of records.

I am using pyodbc module on python

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For pyodbc, `cursor.execute()` [returns the cursor object itself](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Features#Cursor.execute_Returns_the_Cursor). You still need to retrieve the results separately.

You could loop over the cursor to get rows; `list()` can do the looping for you and pull in all rows into a list object:

```
cursor.execute("select count(*) from fixtures")  
print(list(cursor))
```

or you can call `cursor.fetchall()`.

For a result set with just one row, you could use:

```
cursor.execute("select count(*) from fixtures")
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

`cursor.fetchone()` returns either one row, or `None` if there are no results at all.

In all cases rows are sequences of columns, for a one-column result that'll be a tuple with just one value in it.

In your example query, you are fetching a single row, with a single column, so you can get that single value with `cursor.fetchone()` then using indexing or tuple assignment, e.g.

```
cursor.execute("select count(*) from fixtures")
fixture_count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

or

```
cursor.execute("select count(*) from fixtures")
fixture_count, = cursor.fetchone()
```

You don't need to commit after a `SELECT`, but you didn't actually *call* the `commit()` method either, you are missing the `()` part. If you are altering data, do remember to use `cursor.commit()`. Note that `cursor.commit()` does exactly the same thing as `cnxn.commit()`; transactions are managed per connection, not per cursor.

However, when not using `autocommit`, it is easier and better to use the connection as a context manager to ensure a transaction is aborted or committed based on there being any exceptions:

```
with cnxn:
    # anything in this block is handled with a transaction.

# after the block the transaction is committed, unless there was an exception.
```

Comment: @user3328431: same way you'd change labels for any other text change. :-) `label_object.set(str(cursor.fetchone()[0]))` ought to do it.

Comment: If I wanted to display an individual **record** in a label in 'tkitner' GUI how would I go about doing so if the output of the cursor is a list?

Comment: It should be `cursor.fetchone()` as per @Xavi Martinez answer, and the docs. There is no underscore!

Answer (score 8):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM fixtures")
rowcount = cursor.fetchone()[0]

print (rowcount)
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
tempvar = cursor.fetchall()
rowcount = len(tempvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with sqlite3. I wrote a function which should simply things if you have to query the database more than once.

```
import sqlite3

def inquire(sql):
    db = sqlite3.connect(my_database.sqlite)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
    db.close()

sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM fixtures"
results = inquire(sql)

print(results)
```